# How can I debug the remote server of a nginx with SSL by PhpStorm 10

Tags: php, debugging, ssl, phpstorm, remote-debugging

I want to do PhpStorm remote debug setting in cloud server which installed nginx with SSL.

For that I did add parameter in `php.ini` like following:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib//xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
;xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back =1
```

and I modify the cloud server as follow

```
using ufw, the 80, 443, 9000 port opened
```

I set up my PhpStorm:

```
1. php web server setting
   host : test.com (example)
   port : 80/443 (I did test it, but didn't work all two case)
   mappings : add local files info and hosting path in absolute path

2. remote debug
   select server info (test.com)
   ide key : PHPSTORM
```

after that I installed xdebug helper in the Chrome browser; changed the IDEKEY to be `PHPSTORM`.

I have downloaded the full source using SFTP from the server, it doesn't need setting up synchronization.

Using above setting I couldn't get a result.

So, I might think, the reason of failure is the SSL environment. But that was just my guess.

If you have been like this case, please give me the tip and example.

PhpStorm web manual is so simple to understand and solve my problem. Please don't leave me PhpStorm web manual links.

Comment: what do you see in xdebug.log ?  is xdebug.log writeable by the nginx process owner ?

Comment: As far as my experience goes -- it has *nothing* to do with SSL (at all). It's all about xdebug/IDE configuration + any possible firewall (as it's xdebug that connects to IDE and not other way around). So .. to start with -- collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session and show what it has to say.